# Sending Alt Shift and Ctrl key combinations from Android Teamviewer

Tags: teamviewer

I can't find anywhere to send Alt Shift and Ctrl key combinations to Windows PC from Android Teamviewer. Anyone able to do this? I don't have any controls on top of the window (either on the android app or the windows host pc). The Android bottom controls pull up my Samsung keyboard or settings but I can't find anything looking like special keys.

As an aside for anyone finding this post in the future and looking for a solution, VNC Viewer does allow for sending special key combos from Android. What it lacks is transferring files (at least in the free version I have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android button controls should have a wrench/tool (or running man?), after that you are supposed to see a button for Ctrl+Alt+Del
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have that. But I want to be able to send key combinations like Alt-F or Ctrl-C. In particular, I have Firefox with the menu hidden. I need to be able to send Alt-F to reveal the menu. There are other cases as well. Looks like Teamviewer decided not support this for some reason. Very frustrating. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: TBH I just googled the info above, never used Teamviewer. Apologize I misunderstood your request. I've used RDP on Android & those functions were part of the Keyboard menu, but guessing thats not same for Teamviewer. Hopefully somebody chimes in with help! Alternatively you could use the Windows On-Screen Keyboard, clunky, but something rather than nothing

Comment: The  On-Screen Keyboard might be clunky, but I thank you for an obvious  solution i never thought of. I have had to give up in Teamviewer when needing to get to hidden menus only available with alt key. Now at least I don't need to exit Teamviewer and load VNV Viewer. Thanks.